# Absorbable stents

Tags: biomedical-engineering

Stents are tubular scaffoldings, which are used to expand blocked arteries. Absorbable stents dissolve after few years. Shouldn't the blood vessel become narrow again once the stent has dissolved?

Comment: Blood vessel by that time gets remodelled.

Comment: "Restenosis" is a problem with both absorbable and non-absorbable stents.